# ASP.NET Core - Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Core.Configuration.RedisConfiguration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redis

In my ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, I am implementing Redis for In-Memory Cache. I installed this extensions:

```
<PackageReference Include="StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.AspNetCore" Version="9.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Newtonsoft" Version="9.1.0" />
```

Then I have this code for the dependency injection:

```
public static class DIServices
{
    public static void AddDI(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddStackExchangeRedisExtensions<NewtonsoftSerializer>( options =>
        {
            return new RedisConfiguration();
        });
    }
}
```

And in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddDI();
```

However, I got this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Core.Configuration.RedisConfiguration' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Core.Configuration.RedisConfiguration>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Also:

```
return new RedisConfiguration()
```

is highlighted.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: this is all very specific to https://github.com/imperugo/StackExchange.Redis.Extensions - if no answer here, maybe ask there? but: none of this is necessary for regular redis in-memory cache with aspnet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that the function is returning a `RedisConfiguration` but it's *expecting* to return an `IEnumerable<RedisConfiguration>`.  An apple is not a basket of apples.

Return a collection instead:

```
return new List<RedisConfiguration> { new RedisConfiguration() };
```